# How to find correct offset to adjust sprite to the position of box2D body after rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, box2d, physics

I am trying to implement phsyics with the as3 box2d port.  I currently have a b2body for each of some certain sprites in my game and I am able to update the sprite's positions correctly from the positions of the bodies.  This is shown in the picture below (debugDraw shows the positions of the b2bodies overlaid on their corresponding spirtes.  The green rectangles are the walls and floor)

[image]

However, I also want to have the sprite's rotations reflect the rotations of the b2bodies.  But, after I rotate the sprites, the offset I use to center them correctly with the b2body positions is no longer accurate.

[image]

My code for updating the sprites positions is as follows:

```
private function Update(update_event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                //step physics simulation forward 
                world.Step(0.025,10,10);



                //update all objects in world
                for each (var obj:HouseItemPhysicsObject in physicsObjects)
                {
                    //update object's position from gravity if it is not being dragged
                    if(!obj.isHeld)
                    {
                        /*adjust rotation of sprite along with body -> yourMC.rotation = (yourMCbody.GetAngle() * 180 / Math.PI) % 360; */
                        obj.object.rotation = (obj.pBody.GetAngle() * 180/Math.PI) % 360;   

                        if(obj.object.rotation >=5)
                        // set object's x position but adjust for offset between the cooridinate systems
                        obj.x = (obj.pBody.GetPosition().x* scaleFactor)-(obj.object.width/2); 
                        //keep in horizontal bounds of screen
                        if(obj.x > GeneralConstants.GAME_WIDTH)
                        {
                            obj.x =GeneralConstants.GAME_WIDTH;
                        }
                        else if(obj.x < 0)
                        {
                            obj.x = 0;
                        }

                        // set object's x position but adjust for offset between the cooridinate systems in Flash and box2d
                        obj.y = (obj.pBody.GetPosition().y * scaleFactor)-(obj.object.height/2);

                        //keep in vertical bounds of the screen
                        if(obj.y > GeneralConstants.GAME_HEIGHT)
                        {
                            obj.y =GeneralConstants.GAME_HEIGHT;
                        }
                        else if(obj.x < 0)
                        {
                            obj.x = 0;
                        }



                        /*Draw shapes to see for debug*/
                        //obj.DrawDebug();
                        //trace("OBJECT's X is :" + obj.x + " Y is :" +obj.y);
                        trace("Object's rotation is:" + obj.object.rotation);
                    }



                }

                //move debug draw to front of display list
                m_sprite.parent.setChildIndex(m_sprite, m_sprite.parent.numChildren - 5);
                world.DrawDebugData();
            }
```

How can I find the correct X and Y offset between the coordinate systems (Flash and Box2d) after rotating the sprite according to the b2Body?  Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**
For clarity, the object is a class that extends the Sprite class, and it's data member _object is a an instance of MovieClip.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Box2D and I'm not in the position to make researches, but: Is there an ability to attach a Sprite to a b2body as a child, most likely? If yes, add and forget.

Comment: What is the `(obj.pBody.GetAngle() * 180/Math.PI) % 360` value at that point? Does it return a negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box2D objects have their anchor point in the center by default, while for Flash objects, it's in the top left. To position them properly, you need to take this into account

**Easy way**

Wrap your `Bitmaps`/whatever in a `Sprite` and center them:

```
// create the image, center it, and add it to a holder Sprite
var image:Bitmap    = new Bitmap( objGraphicsBitmapData );
image.x             = -image.width * 0.5;
image.y             = -image.height * 0.5;
var holder:Sprite   = new Sprite;
holder.addChild( image );
```

Now just set the position and rotation of holder as you do currently, and it should be fine

**Hard way**

You need to manually adjust the position offset based on the object's rotation. A simple rotation function:

```
public function rotate( p:Point, radians:Number, out:Point = null ):Point
{
    // formula is:
    // x1 = x * cos( r ) - y * sin( r )
    // y1 = x * sin( r ) + y * cos( r )
    var sin:Number  = Math.sin( radians );
    var cos:Number  = Math.cos( radians );
    var ox:Number   = p.x * cos - p.y * sin;
    var oy:Number   = p.x * sin + p.y * cos;

    // we use ox and oy in case out is one of our points
    if ( out == null )
        out = new Point;
    out.x = ox;
    out.y = oy;
    return out;
}
```

First we need to store the object's offset - this is normally `new Point( -obj.width * 0.5, -obj.height * 0.5 )`. You need to stock this while it's rotation is `0`, and rotating the object will change its `width` and `height` properties, so the following won't work properly.

```
obj.offset = new Point( -obj.width * 0.5, -obj.height * 0.5 );
```

When you're updating the position, simply rotate the offset by the rotation and add it:

```
// get our object's position and rotation
// NOTE: you'll probably need to adjust the position based on your pixels per meter value
var pos:Point   = new Point( obj.pBody.GetPosition().x, obj.pBody.GetPosition().y ); // pos in screen coords
var rotR:Number = obj.pBody.GetAngle();     // rotation in radians
var rotD:Number = radiansToDegrees( rotR ); // rotation in degrees

// rotate our offset by our rotation
var offset:Point = rotate( obj.offset, rotR );

// set our position and rotation
obj.x           = pos.x + offset.x;
obj.y           = pos.y + offset.y;
obj.rotation    = rotD;
```

Other useful functions:

```
public function degreesToRadians( deg:Number ):Number
{
    return deg * ( Math.PI / 180.0 );
}
public function radiansToDegrees( rad:Number ):Number
{
    return rad * ( 180.0 / Math.PI );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do it to give your sprites properties of physical objects, it can be easier to use physInjector for box2D:

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/03/27/add-box2d-physics-to-your-projects-in-a-snap-with-physinjector/

It is free can do it in a couple of lines.